# Injeção de dependencia em service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, services

Galera eu consigo fazer injeção de dependencia em services? por exemplo, tentei isso:

serviço 1

`var crypto = angular.module('crypto',['ngRoute']);`

serviço 2

```
var teste = angular.module('userlog',['crypto']);
teste.service('userlogService','cryptoService', function (cryptoService) {
```

porém está dando erro

Answer (score 1):

No serviço, funciona de forma diferente:

```
var teste = angular.module('userlog',['crypto']);

teste.service('seuService', ['userlogService','cryptoService', function (userlogService, cryptoService) {
//aqui o serviço
}]);
```

Se você não vai usar em outro lugar, você também pode fazer assim somente:

```
  teste.service('seuService', function (userlogService, cryptoService) {
    //aqui o serviço
    });
```

Se você pretende utilizar vários métodos dentro de um mesmo serviço, eu recomendo que você utilize um factory ao invés de service:

```
 var teste = angular.module('userlog',['crypto']);

 teste.factory('seuService', function () {

      function seuService() {

          var userlogService = function(scope) {
          //service 1
          };

          var cryptoService = function(scope) {
          //service 2
          }; 
      }
      return new seuService(); 
    });
```

Usando no controller seria algo como isso:

```
teste.controller('seuController',['seuService',function(seuService) {
    seuService().userlogService($scope);
    seuService().cryptoService($scope);
}]);
```

Comment: eu não sei se entendi corretamente, mas a minha ideia é fazer modulos em diferentes arquivos, trabalharem modularmente tipo: moduloDeSegurança>(depende)moduloDeLoginDeUsuario>(depende)moduloDeConexão. reaproveitando as funções dentro dos services e controllers, parecido com java, onde importa-se a classe, cria-se uma instancia e usa-se os metodos da classe importada

Comment: Você pode, até deveria dizer (deve), trabalhar modularmente, entretanto, quando seu módulo só pertente a um tipo de uso, como login de usuário, nas faz muito sentido segmentar seu sistema quando não terá uso fora do mesmo escopo. Só uma sugestão.

Comment: o modulo de login seria para verificar não só a autorização de logar, mas também para usar os serviços, tipo ele vai ter que estar presente o tempo todo, entende?

Comment: ok, mas você entendeu né...

Comment: mais ou menos kk sou novo na parada, to tendo que aprender na raça, e to com um pouco de difculdade em reaproveitar codigos denro dos modulos